# How to make JSP project live on Internet?

Tags: html, jsp, web, web-hosting

I have made a project in eclipse in HTML and JSP . I want to make it online or live . I have tried hostinger.in , 000webhost.com and also wordpress.com . But no one is supporting to host JSP pages . I don't want to purchase any domain name as it is just made for fun and my knowledge .

Comment: why not try aws create your own stack (most likely a jetty or tomcat container that can serve your JSP page) in it and host there. It has a free tier for 1 year

Comment: I don't have credit or debit card . And for AWS you have to give your card details  . I have tried to take trial on AWS for that but in that they also asks for credit or debit card .